# Limit Memory Access on LangChain Bot

Tags: python, langchain

I'm creating a langchain chatbot (Conversationl-ReACT-description) with zep long term memory and that bot has access to real-time data. How do I prevent use the memory when same query asked again few minutes later?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cache mechanism to control this behavior, also you can modify this basis your specific need..

```
    cache = {}
    memory_duration = 300 # this is seconds

    if query in cache:
        timestamp, response = cache[query]
        # Check if the cached response is within the time window
        if time.time() - timestamp < memory_duration:
            return response

        # If not process the query
        response = process_query(query) #Here you can define your own function to process the query

        # Store the response and current timestamp in cache
        cache[query] = (time.time(), response)


    --------------------------------------------------- 


    #you can create separate function to delete outdated data from cache
    current_time = time.time()
    keys_to_delete = [key for key, (timestamp, _) in cache.items() if current_time - timestamp > memory_duration]
    for key in keys_to_delete:
        del cache[key]
```

Comment: Yeah, I think dynamically comparing the last message and the new message will help to solve this.